# Ubuntu 20.xx SAMBA problem

Tags: samba, 20.10, smb

It's been a while since I used SAMBA to access network shares. It was working fine in 19.xx, but I think it may be broken in 20.04 and 20.10 (I'm using 20.10).

I can't access the shares on my own local computer, although I seem to be able to access shares on my router. It pops up an error dialog, with a message about "Failed to retrieve share list from server"? Sorry, I don't remember the exact error message.

I **think** I know what might be the problem. It seems that SMB1 may have been disabled for security reasons, but SMB2/3 may still be there. I don't exactly know how to find this out.

`testparm` passed. `findsmb` and `smbtree` didn't work (but they now do, after the following patch).

I edited /etc/samba/smb.conf and added the following to the network section...

```
client min protocol = NT1
server min protocol = NT1
name resolve order = bcast host lmhosts wins
```

restarted smbd and nmbd, and that seems to have fixed it. I **think** that this re-enables SMB1... but I'm no SAMBA expert here.

Now `smbstatus` shows...

```
Samba version 4.12.5-Ubuntu
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
24943   nobody       nogroup      satellite-e55 (ipv6:fe80::c433:26d6:91d2:3475:59876) NT1               -                    -                    
19177   nobody       nogroup      satellite-e55 (ipv4:192.168.0.100:57868)  NT1               -                    -                    

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IPC$         19177   satellite-e55 Sat Mar 20 07:17:40 PM 2021 PDT  -            -           
IPC$         24943   satellite-e55 Sun Mar 21 07:56:25 AM 2021 PDT  -            -           

No locked files
```

Is this what's happening, and did I implement the correct/best fix? What happened in 20.xx that might have caused this problem?

**Update #1:**

nmap --script smb-protocols IPofServer/32

My router...

```
~$ nmap --script smb-protocols 192.168.0.1/32
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-22 07:01 PDT
Nmap scan report for caspurr.local (192.168.0.1)
Host is up (0.012s latency).
Not shown: 986 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
53/tcp    open  domain
80/tcp    open  http
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
548/tcp   open  afp
631/tcp   open  ipp
5000/tcp  open  upnp
8200/tcp  open  trivnet1
9100/tcp  open  jetdirect
9101/tcp  open  jetdirect
9102/tcp  open  jetdirect
9103/tcp  open  jetdirect
20005/tcp open  btx
49152/tcp open  unknown

Host script results:
| smb-protocols: 
|   dialects: 
|     NT LM 0.12 (SMBv1) [dangerous, but default]
|     2.02
|     2.10
|     3.00
|     3.02
|_    3.11

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.21 seconds
```

My PC...

```
~$ nmap --script smb-protocols 192.168.0.100/32
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-03-22 07:03 PDT
Nmap scan report for ubuntu-eth0.local (192.168.0.100)
Host is up (0.00012s latency).
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
139/tcp open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp open  microsoft-ds
631/tcp open  ipp

Host script results:
| smb-protocols: 
|   dialects: 
|     NT LM 0.12 (SMBv1) [dangerous, but default]
|     2.02
|     2.10
|     3.00
|     3.02
|_    3.11
```

Comment: Is there any useful information in `/var/log/samba`? And have you tried increasing the log level via `smb.conf`? All I remember is that I had troubles getting samba operational on 20.04, but I also had troubles between 10.04 and 12.04 and 14.04 and... I know you don't go there anymore, but consider Ubuntu forums for your question, as there is a samba expert that still seems to look there sometimes. Also the server team has updated the [samba chapter of the Ubuntu serverguide](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/samba-introduction).

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks for the good information. I know there's someone here on AU named mobius... or something close... and I hope will jump in to comment also.

Comment: Try running `nmap --script smb-protocols IPofServer/32`

Comment: @Terrance Updated my question with the nmap output.

Comment: I used [wsdd](https://github.com/christgau/wsdd/) on 18.04 to solve the 'retrieve share list' problem.  Not sure how it turns out in 20.xx.

Comment: Thanks a lot... you deserve a kiss, so helpful to the communiy =) it only surprises me HOW ubuntu team KILLS such a important software for millions in a upgrade... =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here - really three - that have combined to cause the issue you reported.

One is a bug in gvfs ( gvfsd-smb-browse ) that is hard-wired to use SMB1 ( NT1 ) to get a list of the servers and their shares when you browse for them in your file manager.

The second one is Sambas decision to disable ( but not remove ) SMB1 on both the client and server side.

Your samba server can run between SMB2.02 to SMB3. The bug in gvfs causes the samba client to try to access that server using SMB1 which the server cannot understand so it throws an error:

> Failed to retrieve share list from server: Invalid argument

There are three ways to get around this issue:

[1] Bypass gvfsd-smb-browse by asking for the server and its share in Connect to Server: `smb://server-host-name.local/share-name`

Samba client and server will connect using SMB3.

[2] OR do what you just did and set the min server and client to SMB1 ( NT1 ). IT will also connect using SMB3 because the server and client negotiate with one another to determine the best dialect to use after the initial SMB1 connection.

[3] OR use a mount.cifs mount which will also connect using SMB3. This has to be set up in fstab to happen automatically.

*If it makes you feel any better a newly installed Win10 machine will not be able to "discover" your samba server at all because it too disabled SMB1. The solution there is the same as for your Linux system: Connect with a `\\server-host-name.local` OR enable SMB1 on the client side of Win10 which Microsoft really doesn't want anyone to do.*

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! `gvfsd-smb-browse` isn't installed on my system, and doesn't appear in the Ubuntu repos for 20.10 any more. If SMB1 was disabled in 20.xx, and since SMB1 is used in the discovery part, how does Canonical expect SAMBA to work any more without my mod? Why does `smbstatus` show NT1 instead of NT2/3?

Comment: ps: After connecting to one of the shares on my PC, `smbstatus` correctly shows a SMB3_11 connection.

Comment: smb-browse isn't a stand alone package. It comes with gvfs-backends. Run `dpkg -L gvfs-backends | grep browse` to verify for yourself.

Comment: Yes, that shows it.

Comment: How does SAMBA work at all in 20.xx if they've disabled SMB1? They've broken SAMBA, no?

Comment: @heynnema have you heard of the ransomware "wanacry"? It got pretty famous a few years ago by disabling heaploads of the British National Health Service hospital equipment (networked computers, plus anything with embedded (already EOL) Windows XP in them (diagnostic equipment, like MRIs)), the Telefonica Spanish telecommunications service provider, and several others worldwide. It all propagated through earlier versions of SMB. That did teach people to avoid these older SMB versions. We should be grateful that it gets disabled.

Comment: @Levente But disabling SMB1 breaks `findsmb` and `smbtree` and connections to network shares, even on my own local PC. On my private network, enabling SMB1 on my local PC running Ubuntu again shouldn't be a ransomware problem, correct?

Comment: Samba itself isn't broken since the client can still access the server w/o SMB1 as long as it asks for the server and share explicitly. What is broken is Samba "discovery" - by NetBIOS name - which is a casualty of disabling SMB1. A MacOS system has no problem discovering then accessing a modern Samba server. It does that because both systems use mDNS publishing and discovery ( Avahi in Linux / Bonjour in MacOS ). MacOS can do that because is has no gvfs. A Linux client cannot because of gvfsd-smb-browse which for some reason is applied even to mDNS connections.

Comment: Thank you!  smb://server-host-name.local/share-name worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.  My windows machine were working fine with my local Samba server but my Ubuntu 20.04.4 machine could not.  Usually in my Ubuntu file browser I would acces the server with :

```
smb://server-host-name.local/share-name
```

but it would not work.

The solution that works for me is replacing the server name by the IP adress of the server. Example:

```
smb://14.15.16.17/share-name
```