# Cleaning up swap issues on Ubuntu Server 20.10

Tags: server, swap

Question spawned from a previous question found here:

[Very long startup time on Ubuntu Server (network configuration)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321443/very-long-startup-time-on-ubuntu-server-network-configuration/1323542#1323542)

I have two swap partitions mounted in my fstab which seems odd.  I'm guessing it's a byproduct of the process of builing a RAID array (maybe I botched something somewhere).

Some relevant logs as suggested by @heynnema:

#### /etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/md2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-4c695059:2f774b0b:9e5492d2:bcb62609 / ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-05f3f447:6002213f:2bb97c81:6416f121 none swap sw 0 0
# /boot was on /dev/md0 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-58dd9ab9:74b02d8a:10890b55:2212c9cb /boot ext4 defaults 0 
0
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

#### `swapon -s`:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swap.img                               file        4194300 0   -2
/dev/md1                                partition   8379388 0   -3
```

#### `ls -al /`:

```
-rw-------   1 root root 4294967296 Jun  9  2020 swap.img
```

#### `free -h`:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.7Gi       1.3Gi       5.0Gi        22Mi       1.4Gi       6.1Gi
Swap:          11Gi          0B        11Gi
```

The output of `fdisk -l` does not list any swap partitions...

Comment: What is the question? Want to remove some of the swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have a 8G swap partition, and a 4G /swap.img file.

To reduce your two swaps down to one...

First unmount both swaps...

`sudo swapoff -a`

Then remove (or comment out) EITHER one of these lines from /etc/fstab using...

`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

---

For 8G swap partition (**see next choice**)...

```
/dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-05f3f447:6002213f:2bb97c81:6416f121 none swap sw 0 0
```

Then delete this swap partition (/dev/md1 or UUID), `sudo swapon -a`, then `reboot`.

---

For 4G /swap.img (**probably easier/safer to do**)...

```
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Then `sudo rm -i /swap.img`, `sudo swapon -a`, then `reboot`.

---

Verify operation with...

`swapon -s`

`free -h`

Comment: Confirmed!  Only one active swap partition - /dev/md1.  Thanks again for the help!