# Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 LTS persistent error systemd-networkd-wait-online.service

Tags: networking, server, systemd

Running Ubuntu server 22.04.2 LTS, runs normally but there is a persistent failed systemd service:  "systemd-networkd-wait-online.service", tried verious things including disabling (doesn't work) masking (again not allowing me to), systemctl status gives me degraded. Output of networkctl is:

```
IDX LINK   TYPE     OPERATIONAL SETUP      
  1 lo     loopback carrier     unmanaged
  2 eno1   ether    routable    configured 
  3 eno2   ether    no-carrier  configuring
  4 usb0   ether    off         unmanaged
  5 virbr0 bridge   no-carrier  unmanaged

5 links listed."
```

I suspect its the eno2 interface, output from systemctl gives:

```
Jul 01 14:00:47 supermicro systemd[1]: Starting Wait for Network to be Configured...
Jul 01 14:00:57 supermicro systemd-networkd-wait-online[7530]: Timeout occurred while waiting for network connectivity.
Jul 01 14:00:57 supermicro systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 01 14:00:57 supermicro systemd[1]: systemd-networkd-wait-online.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 01 14:00:57 supermicro systemd[1]: Failed to start Wait for Network to be Configured.
```

The server is connected to a router via RJ45 cable and there is only one ethernet socket on the motherboard.  Not sure what else to do? Any assistance welcome.....

Answer (score 1):

You can add `RequiredForOnline=no` to the config of "eno2" and it will not check the online status for the interface.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html

Comment: Nice workaround +1 ... Probably also `eno2` configuration is worth a deeper check to correct the issue making it take so long to process/configure ... Also a pointer to the configuration file and the process to add `RequiredForOnline=no` would make it easier to apply.

Comment: @Raffa thanks for the remark. It is always the question: "How much of the manual should be copied in the answer?"

Comment: Thanks chaps, managed to sort the annoying error message, had to acquaint myself with Netplan and YAML, was used to working with NetworkManager but edited the YAML config to point to NetworkManager as the renderer, which solved the problem.....

Answer (score 1):

Mark the second interface as optional at boot with https://askubuntu.com/a/1323542:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
```

```yaml
network:
  ethernets:
    eno2:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true    # add this
```